# How to get value of dynamically generated checkboxes if the checkbox is true in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing angularjs application. I have generated checkboxes dynamically using ng-repeat. My design is as below.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="screen in screenMap">
        <input type="text" ng-model="screen.scrn_name" />
        <input type="hidden" value="{{screen.scrn_id}}" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Read">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Write">
        <br>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="APPLY" ng-click="apply()" />
```

Below is my js code.

```
 $scope.apply = function () {

        }
```

I want to get array like scrn_name,true,false format. If the checkbox is checked then true else false.
May i know how can i get this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: check angular doc for [check box](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go through [angular checkbox](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

use `ng-true-value` and `ng-true-value`

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="screen in screenMap">
<input type="text" ng-model="screen.scrn_name" />
<input type="hidden" value="{{screen.scrn_id}}"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" ng-model="screen.write" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" ng-model="screen.read" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"><br>
</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="APPLY" ng-click="apply()"/>


$scope.apply = function () {
  console.log($scope.screenMap);//[{..,read:true,write:false},...]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i loop through above textbox and checkboxes?

Comment: create an object array to store checkbox values

Comment: Thank you.  $scope.storechecboxvalues = {}; This is the right way if i am not wrong?

Comment: actulayy i tried   angular.forEach(screenMap, function (value, key) { }); This gives me error screenMap is not defined. May i know the cause of the error?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole it should be angular.forEach($scope.screenMap, function (value, key) { });

Comment: I got values of $scope.screenMap but checbox values i did not get. How can i get textbox true or false values? because my textbox does not contain scope values.    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1">

Comment: if the checkboxMode.length and screenMap.length are same do like this `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxMode[$index]l.value1">`

Comment: i have created plunker here. https://plnkr.co/edit/TPEL2q2yILMBgv9nkQhT?p=preview

Comment: why you using two checkboxes?

Comment: I want two checkboxes as per requirement. One for read and one for write.

Comment: then you permission object must have two property for read and write, bind those properties to checkboxes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148397/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-azad).